# How to change the folder path for swp files in Vim

Tags: vim, swapfile

I'm working at a project on a remote server. I don't want to have the swap files on the server.  I would like  all swap files for Vim (and, of course, gVim) to be saved on the specified directory. How could I do that?

Comment: Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43286164/30038) on how to do it in Windows.

Comment: Recommended answer for you to check out: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/how-can-put-vimrc-and-viminfo-into-vim-directory/20067#20067

Answer (score 102):

You can set the `directory` option to the location that you want vim to store its swap files, e.g.:

```
 mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/swapfiles  # this dir must exist vi does not create it

" $HOME/.vimrc
:set directory=$HOME/.vim/swapfiles//
```

I use trailing double path separators because, from the help docs:

> For Unix and Win32, if a directory ends in two path separators "//" or "\\", the swap file name will be built from the complete path to the file with all path separators substituted to percent '%' signs. This will ensure file name uniqueness in the preserve directory.

Comment: This assumes you've set your HOME dir with:
set HOME=~/     "or whatever location you like
If you did not do this, use:
set directory=~/.vim/swapfiles// "make sure that directory exists

Comment: How can i achieve this same thing on a PC running Windows 10? How would the path differ?

Comment: @currenthandle That worked on my Windows 10. Usually, the only difference is that `.vim` folder is instead called `vimfiles`. And `mkdir -p` probably won't work, so just create the folder in some other way (`md` or via Explorer).

Answer (score 39):

You might want to consider setting the backupdir options as well:

```
set backupdir=Z:\backups
```

That makes vim store backups in a specific location rather than in the current directory.

Comment: What if you edit two files with the exact same name that are in two different locations. Will there be a conflict in Z:\backups?

Comment: @trusktr To avoid that problem you do this : :set dir=>D:\data\vimdata\vswaps// where the double slashes on the end of the path cause Vim to ensure the file in the swaps directory is always unique. This example, obviously, is from a windows enviroment but I believe the same applies for other platforms.