# Hiding swp, ~ files in the default Vim file browser

Tags: vim, file-browser

I'm using the default file browser in Vim a *lot*. But the annoyance is that it's showing swap files, `.orig`, `.php~` etc. Can I hide these files somehow?

On a related note, why doesn't Vim always return to the file browser when pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the folder path for swp files in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636297/how-to-change-the-folder-path-for-swp-files-in-vim)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you want to move the swap and backup files to another (single) directory (as outlined in the answer of the Tin Man), you have to configure the built-in *netrw* plugin (which provides the file browser), as described in `:help g:netrw_list_hide`:

```
:let g:netrw_list_hide= '.*\.swp$,\~$,\.orig$'
```

Put this into your `~/.vimrc` to make it permanent.

Answer (score 6):

Vim lets you define where your backup and swap files reside. It's pretty common to tell Vim to use either a local tmp directory (`~/tmp`), or a somewhere else semi-out-of-the-way.

You can define the location using the following commands in your `$MYVIMRC` file (typically ~/.vimrc). I use:

```
set backup                    " keep a backup file
set backupdir=~/.vim/_backups " store backups here
set directory=~/.vim/_swaps   " store swap files here
```

I've created `_backups` and `_swaps` in my ~/.vim directory.

Use `h directory` and `h backupdir` in Vim to read the documentation about the two settings.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this files appears because Vim was closed before the buffer was written to its original file/location. Always enter `:write` or `:update` before quitting Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd>, try `:Rex`.

With netrw v151, `:Rex` can also return from the netrw browser to the last file being edited in that window, too.