# Exclude Vim *.sw* files from angular-cli auto rebuild

Tags: angular, vim, angular-cli

This is related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2425 where the end result was to remove the files from `angular-cli.json`

How do I modify the `angular-cli.json` file to ignore certain file extensions?

Ideally I would have it ignore `*.swp` so that `ng serve` doesn't rebuild every time I type inside of vim.

Comment: There is some discussion on GitHub about this as well --> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4593.

Comment: Easiest solution here would be to tell vim to store .swp files in /tmp/ directory. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636297/how-to-change-the-folder-path-for-swp-files-in-vim).