# How can I prevent swap/backup files in VIM for one specific file?

Tags: vim

I've got this password file, and when editing this in vim I want to make sure vim does not create a swap/backup file. How to set this?

I have seen this:
[How to prevent vim from creating (and leaving) temporary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743150/how-to-prevent-vim-from-creating-and-leaving-temporary-files)

But I do not want this for all files, just for a specific one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file can contain comments you can set the nobackup and noswapfile by adding a [modeline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) to the start or end of the file.

Something like this:

```
# vim: set nobackup noswapfile:
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `autocmd` to `set nobackup` for that filename or filenames matching a specific pattern/extension:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile passwordfilename set nobackup
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile passwordfilename set noswapfile
```