# How can I prevent vim from creating backup files and undo files on Windows 10?

Tags: vim

I have tried editing my **_vimrc** file. However, I am unable to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743150/how-to-prevent-vim-from-creating-and-leaving-temporary-files).

You should try

```
set nobackup #no backup files 
set nowritebackup #only in case you don't want a backup file while editing 
set noswapfile #no swap files
```