# How to ignore files with nativescript tns run?

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to ignore files being watched for changes in nativescript?

running `tns run android`

every time I travel over folders, or open a file for read with vim explorer it generates tmp files, so Nativescript is reloading the app every second until it's unable to refresh.

Comment: I don't think you can specify files to ignore but you could change the directory that Vim uses to store it's temp files to a directory outside of your project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743150/how-to-prevent-vim-from-creating-and-leaving-temporary-files

Comment: Thanks @Turnip!!! this is a great workaround!