# How to set a directory to store swap files when using Vim on Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, vim

I am trying to set a directory for swap files when using Vim on Git Bash. In my .vimrc file at  C:\Users\***USERNAME***\.vim (***USERNAME*** is replaced with my account name), I added a line\

```
set directory=C:\Users\USERNAME\.vim\swap//
```

But, it does not work. Vim can not put swap files into the directory. How can I set the directory for swap files Vim creates on Git Bash environment? Note that I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286164/8344060) useful to you?

Comment: Be careful with the backslashes. You may need to escape them and so instead of C:\Users\USERNAME\.vim\swap C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\.vim\\swap. Alternatively, you may be able to use /c/Users/USERNAME/.vim/swap

Comment: >kvantour I could not understand it before I asked here, but now I got it!

Comment: > Raman Sailopal It worked! Thank you very much.