# GVIM on windows: way to disable the tmp file creation

Tags: vim

I use gvim on windows and I want to know a way to disable the temp file(ending in ~) file creation. Also is there a problem if we do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Vim save files with a ~ extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607435/why-does-vim-save-files-with-a-extension)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can disable the backup file by putting this line in your .vimrc:

```
set nobackup
```

I almost always do this, as the ~ file is more annoying that useful.  There is no problem with doing this, you'll just lose the ability to revert to a backup of the file.

If you want to get rid of the temporary .swp (swap) file too, you can also set this:

```
set noswapfile
```

The swap file is created when you have a file open, and provides some backup/recovery security, in case Vim crashes while editing a file.  It also can prevent multiple Vims from editing the same file.  I usually just turn this off too, because I rarely have a use for it.  The .swp file isn't as annoying as the ~ file, because it goes away when you close Vim, but I still just turn that feature off.

Comment: Excepting the fact that you have no chance of recovery in case of vim crashing, or (much more likely, depending on your environment) a severed terminal.

Comment: Yeah, you do lose the backup capability, but I've almost never had a problem with Vim crashing or losing a connection, so I roll the dice.

Comment: ... which is why you save early, and often. First rule of development.

Comment: @Crates Which is great.. until saving often means you just accidentally overwrote something important. Then you realize you were halfway up the undo stack and accidentally typed a letter losing all redo-able changes. Unlikely, but it's happened to me once or twice. Though admittedly, never in Vim. (Visual Studio likes to randomly discard the undo stack sometimes.. a most heinous bug).

Answer (score 28):

It's not quite what you asked for, but something that I've found works well is to redirect the swap and backup files to a seperate, dedicated folder.  That way, they're still there if I need them, but they're not cluttering up the folder I'm working in.

The `_vimrc` file can be created in any of the following locations:

- `%HOMEPATH%\_vimrc`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`

The following lines in the `_vimrc` file put backup files into a temporary directory:

```
set backup
set dir=%TMP%
set backupdir=%TMP%
set directory=%TMP%
set noundofile
```

The last line prevents the proliferation of undo files.

Comment: This is the correct solution for Windows, all the others (like 'set nobackup') had no affect at all.

Answer (score 7):

put these in your vimrc file

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
```

Answer (score 4):

From inside `vim`:

```
:e $HOME/_vimrc
```

and add this to the file:

```
set nobackup
```

Then, `$HOME/_vimrc~` will hopefully be the last backup that vim makes!

Comment: But what if I have my `_vimrc` in `$VIM` instead of `$HOME`? ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the _vimrc from $VIM. 
The _vimrc file from your home dir will be loaded later and the last setting wins.
Beware when using a common dir for backup, swap or undo files.
If you are on an USB or network drive and a drive letter gets reused you may run into problems.