# Disable any kind of backup/swap file?

Tags: windows, vim

After following [those answeres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197749) and [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821902) to the exact same question and setting

```
set nobackup
set noswapfile
set nowritebackup
set updatecount=0
```

my (g)vim still keeps creating local backup files on `:w` and doesn't delete them on exit. Setting `backupskip="*"` doesn't seem to have any effect either. **How do I get rid of any kind of temporary file?** No local tmp files, no tmp directory, no delete-on-exit-solution, just use the memory and memory only to edit files.

I know that my vimrc is not ignored, because all other setting (e.g. colorscheme, tabsize) are not ignored

Comment: Verify your options are not being overwritten elsewhere e.g. try `verbose set backup?`

Comment: With some file opened in gvim I just ran `set [option]?` on all of those four options above and it always returned `no[option]` (or `updatecount=0`), so I think they are not overritten anywhere.

Comment: I see, also make sure that the files being generated are backup files (`filename~`) and not undo files (`.filename~`). If you want to disable undo files do `set noundofile`

Comment: Seems to be an undo file... Didn't know those even existed; Redirecting the undo directory solved the problem so far, but is there a way to transfer those into memory as well?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by "how to transfer undo files into memory".

Comment: Vim should keep its undo history in memory and discard it on exit. `set noundofile` seems to do the trick.