# Vim error E510: Can't make backup file (add ! to override)

Tags: windows, vim, vi

I am using Vim on Windows and decided to create a separate directory for all my `backup files` created by vim.

I am using Vim from my `command prompt` and not using the vim GUI(gVim).

I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625850/1222595) and added the following lines in my `_vimrc`

```
set backup
set backupdir = D:\\VimTemp
```

I have already created `D:\VimTemp` on my system.

Now whenever I try to save changes to my file using `:w` I get the following error message

```
"PenProperties.py" E510: Can't make backup file (add ! to override)
```

I have already tried setting the backupdir in the following ways:

- set backupdir = D:\\VimTemp
- set backupdir = "D:\\VimTemp"
- set backupdir = "D:\\VimTemp\\"
- set backupdir = "D:\VimTemp"

Now, I have already looked at similar questions on stackoverflow but the problem is still there.

So, my question is how to make this work properly.

Comment: You should also consider _set dir=_ which will move vim _swap_ files somewhere. See :help dir and note the _//_ syntax at the end ov the value, which will uniquify the filenames in the directory by prepending a string representing the path.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kill the spaces around =

```
set backupdir=D:\\VimTemp
```

should work if you've created the directory.

Comment: also: don't neglect the help command for vim problems --> :help backupdir

Comment: Nice. It Worked. Thanks a lot man and yes from next time I will first look at `vim help`.

Comment: @SJMP what platform are you running gvim in? The above uses windows-specific path naming conventions, so if you're running under linux/OSX then you'll need to adjust the command to point to the actual directory that you're trying to use. Also note that the command assumes the existence of the directory _VimTemp_ on the _D_ drive: If you're in windows, have you created that directory?

Comment: I am running on Windows. I got it now. Thank you :-)

Comment: My problem was that I used single slash character for paths.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can do by setting in editor-
:verbose set backupdir?