# vim unique backup files

Tags: vim, backup

I want to have a backup folder with the unique backups (*~ files) like I have with my undo history.
For undo I can use:

```
set undofile
set undodir=~/.vim/.undo//
```

to get unique files due to the '`//`' ending. Is there a way to do the same for my backup files?

```
set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim/.backup//
```

just create '`filename~`' copies, so they will be overwritten if I work on files with the same name.

I am using Vim 7.4.488

Comment: Problem has been fixed as of Vim  8.1.0251. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014842/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

`au BufWritePre * let &bex = '-' . strftime("%Y%b%d%X") . '~'`

You can also add a file path by

`au BufWritePre * let &bex = '-' . substitute(expand('%:p:h'),'[\,/]','%','g') . '-' . strftime("%Y%b%d%X") . '~'`

- [`:h backupext`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27backupext%27)
- [`:h substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29)

---

More reading about why the `'//'` ending doesn't work in the case of `'backupdir'` I refer to Ingo Karkat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26779916).

Comment: This is a start but doesn't really help as I suck with vim script. Appending the time makes the files unique as I want, but it is very ugly to identify which backup belongs to which file. A solution would be to use `expand('%:p') . '~'` as `backupext`. How do you replace the delimiters with `'%'`?

Comment: strftime("%X") produces string with ':'. It causes errors on Windows. Also Window file path contains ':' and we need to substitute is also. This command works for me on Windows: au BufWritePre * let &bex = '-' . substitute(expand('%:p:h'),'[\,/,:]','%','g') . '~'