# Untracked files after git add

Tags: git

Whenever I use 'git add X' and then when I run git status it shows the file is in the staging area but there's an untracked file named 'X~'. Why does this happen and what exactly does it mean?

Comment: I know vim can do that (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607435/why-does-vim-save-files-with-a-extension).

Answer (score 2):

Some text editors (for example, gedit) make backup copies of files you edit. They save them under name `<original-file-name>~`.

You have two options:

1) configure your editor not to save backup copies, or

2) add line `*~` to the file `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be left as a backup file by a text editor.

You can add `*~` to your `.gitignore`, in order for `git status` to ignore those files.