# Configure gvim swap, undo, and backup files on windows

Tags: powershell, vim, windows-10

I installed `vim` on windows 10 using [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/). When I edit a  `foo` file in `powershell`, `vim` leaves behind `.foo.un~` or `.foo~` files. What are these and how do I stop `vim` from leaving them around?

Comment: Heath, could you please refrain from posting questions specific to software on a programming questions site, _(three questions all specfic to VIM)_. Please use [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) for software related issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'll move it there.

Comment: Moved to superuser: https://superuser.com/q/1564618/42083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are [`backup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/607475/9636) and [`undo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27undofile%27) files. `vim` also creates [`swap`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/179) files if it crashes while editing.

From https://coderwall.com/p/sdhfug/vim-swap-backup-and-undo-files

In `powershell`, create the following directories:

```
~/.vim
~/.vim/.undo
~/.vim/.backup
~/.vim/.swp
```

Edit your `.vimrc` file by opening vim and typing:

```
:edit $MYVIMRC
```

Then, add the following lines, and save:

```
set undodir=~/.vim/.undo//
set backupdir=~/.vim/.backup//
set directory=~/.vim/.swp//
```

`vim` will now put your `undo`, `backup`, and `swap` files in the `~/.vim/.undo`, `~/.vim/.backup`, and `~/.vim/.swp` directories, respectively.

Comment: Moved to superuser: https://superuser.com/a/1564619/42083